# Nested for loop issue in closures javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am using nested for loop in JS after loop completes I am pushing value into an array. But I end up having the same values( last values in the end)

```
for (ii=0;i<cond1;ii++) {
    for (iii=0;j<cond2;iii++) {
        if (response[ii].monitorList[iii].monitorId === $scope.user._id){
            // some code
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the last value in all elements of userdataArray

Comment: Put `const listUserConfigData = {}` or something similar after the `if` statement

Comment: I defined userconfig data outside the loop

Comment: Don't. Define it inside, else you'll be pushing that same mutated object to `userdataArray` each iteration

Comment: Declare `ii` and `iii` within the loops with `let`: `(let ii=0;....`

Comment: Thanks that worjed, may I why it didn't work when I kept const listuser outside the loop

Comment: Because everytime you were accessing the same object and updating its value. By declaring inside, you are now creating a new instance of the object on every iteration.